# LPTHW ex. 45, how to return functions from a class in another module?

Tags: python, class, module

Trying to make my own RPG character generator for ex 45 in Zed Shaw's LPTHW. Part of the assignment is to make a new class for each 'room' of the program, like `WelcomeScreen` or `ChooseMutations`.

Here is the main program.

```
import rooms

class Program(object):

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def run(self):
        next_room_name = self.start

        while True:
            room = getattr(self, next_room_name)
            next_room_name = room()

x = rooms.WelcomeRoom()

Program(x.hello_user())
```

And here is the `rooms` file its trying to pull stuff from.

```
class WelcomeRoom(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hello_user(self):
        print '*' * 79
        print '\n'
        print '\t\tWelcome to the'
        print '\t\tMetamorphosis Alpha Character & Random Encounter Generator'
        print '\t\tProgrammed poorly by Raymond Weiss'
        print '\n'
        print '*' * 79
        raw_input('Please press enter to continue')
        return 'get_name'

    def get_name(self):

        name = raw_input('Hello, whats your name?', 
                 '\n',
                 ':> ')
```

But when I run the main program in python, it just logs out instead of returning the function `get_name()` from `rooms`. Output posted below.

```
Raymond-Weisss-MacBook-Pro:macgre Raylug$ python macgre.py
*******************************************************************************


        Welcome to the
        Metamorphosis Alpha Character & Random Encounter Generator
        Programmed poorly by Raymond Weiss


*******************************************************************************
Please press enter to continue
Raymond-Weisss-MacBook-Pro:macgre Raylug$
```

I apologize in advance if my question title isn't exactly what im trying to ask, as a newbie its sometimes hard not knowing what exactly to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a string, not a function (or function result).  You probably want something like:

```
def hello_user(self):
    return self.get_name
```

or

```
def hello_user(self):
    return self.get_name()
```

Based on your program, I think you probably want the second one.  The difference is that the first one returns the `get_name` **function**, whereas the second one returns the **results** of the `get_name` function.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I'll accept it as an answer as soon as it lets me.